# Formatting an input with angular makes it read only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

So I have a model called policyEngine and there is a number field called netPrem

I have it like this so it shows the currency with decimal places.

```
<input class="form-control" name="policyNet"  type="text"
       data-ng-model="QuoteEngineController.policyEngine.netPrem | currency : QuoteEngineController.currency : 2" />
```

The value shows how I like it 
£5,968.63

but I am then unable to change it..?

Thanks

Comment: you don't apply currency filter on input filed directly. Otherwise during editing/typing it would break the number and return _undefined_, e.g. `£` or `£5,96` or `.63` are not valid

Comment: Ok, I am going to format it on the backend first in a string, and use that instead of a number.

Comment: that is less hassle! :)

Comment: you need masking for that kind of functionality check these directives 
http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/

Comment: You could create a custom directive that uses the `$parsers` and `$formatters` of the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Comment: I used an angular directive with a template, that was perfect as i can bind the the model which is a number, then display it as a string, then whenever someone changes the text the string casts back to the model again. :) i will paste in the code when im home. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, a directive that binds to an outside controllers model (decimal) and displays it as eye candy string. When the user changes the string this updates the model by converting back to a decimal again.

```
module CompanyNameHere {
export function showCurrencyInput(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: "<input class='form-control' name=''name'' type='text' ng-model='modelAsString' />",
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            currency: '=',
            name:'=',
            modelAsString: '&',
        },
        link: function (scope: any) { 

            scope.modelAsString = "";

            scope.$watch('model', function (newValue:number, oldValue:number) {

                //put number in eye fiendly string
                if (newValue != null && !isNaN(newValue)) {    
                    var name = scope.name;
                    var currency = scope.currency;                        
                    //number to string
                    var test = newValue.toString();
                    test = test.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                    test = currency + test;
                    scope.modelAsString = test;
                }

            });
            scope.$watch('modelAsString', function (newValue: string, oldValue: string) {

                //put string value back in the number (this goes back to server)
                if (newValue != null) {                       

                    var name = scope.name;
                    var numAsString = newValue;                                                                       
                    //get rid of non numeric characters
                    numAsString = numAsString.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
                    var inputAsNum = parseFloat(numAsString);                        
                    scope.model = inputAsNum;              
                }

            });
        }
    };
}
angular.module("App").directive("showCurrencyInput", showCurrencyInput);
```

}